# Как сделать двойной клик?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть `div` блоки в виде папок. Как сделать, что бы при первом клике ссылка переходила в состояния выделения, а уже при втором клике открывалась? Например как в `Windows`.

[image: ссылка в виде папки] [image: вид ссылки при первом клике на нее]

И если у меня выделена 1 папка, то когда я выделяю 2 папку с 1 папки выделение должно убраться.

Есть примерный код

```js
$('.folder').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    alert('Opening folder..');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).children('.folder__description').show();
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #F2F3F5;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.folder {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.folder:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
.folder.active {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.folder__title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.folder__description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="folder">
  <div class="folder__title">New Folder</div>
  <div class="folder__description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Или по ссылке – http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWBBOW

Вообщем хочу сделать как в файловом менеджере при первом клике на папку в сайдбаре показалась информация из БД а при втором клике она открывалась!

\\UPD///
и как мне из БД вывести доп. информацию о папке, если у меня их например 20шт. на странице? а folder__description не в диве folder а отдельно в сайдбаре??

UPDATE:
@АлексейШиманский  спасибо, я теперь не могу понять как подставить ссылку в двойной клик, делаю так:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '.wellprod', function() {
  $('.wellprod').removeClass('active_c');

  $(this).addClass('active_c');
  location.href = link;
});
```

где `link` это переменная с ссылкой, все ок, но эта ссылка получается одна для всех папок на странице, а мне нужно `site.com/view.php?id={ID}` или если это не категория то `site.com/edit.php?id={ID}` где `{ID}` - это уникальный идентификатор из БД

Comment: [javascript event dblclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dblclick), [jQuery event dblclick](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)

Comment: пригодиться и вот это: [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)

Comment: Вообщем хочу сделать как в файловом менеджере при первом клике на папку в сайдбаре показались свойства из БД а при втором клике она открывалась!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как в комментариях отметил @Grundy - можно воспользоваться готовыми решениями библиотек и самого `javascript`

javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dblclick - правда неизвестно есть ли поддержка у мобильников.

Jquery:
https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Пример:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clicked-div', function() {
  $('.clicked-div').children('div').hide();
  $('.clicked-div').removeClass('active');
  
  $('#infobar').text($(this).children('div').text());
  
});


$(document).on('dblclick', '.clicked-div', function() {
  $('.clicked-div').removeClass('active');

  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
 div.clicked-div {
   background: blue;
   color: white;
   height: 100px;
   width: 150px;
   margin: 10px;
    background: url(http://www.large-icons.com/stock-icons/large-symbol/closed_folder-icon.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat;
 }
 .clicked-div > div {
   display: none;
 }
 div.dbl {
   background: yellow;
   color: black;
 }
 .clicked-div.active {
   background: url(http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/128/toolbar-icons-2/opened-folder.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
 }
   
   #infobar {
     display: inline-block;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clicked-div">
  <div>some info1</div>
</div>

<div class="clicked-div">
  <div>some info2</div>
</div>

<div class="clicked-div">
  <div>some info3</div>
</div>

<div id="infobar-wrap">
  <span>clicked folder info:</span> <span id="infobar"></span>
<div>
```

А если изобретать свой велосипед, то может поможет вот это:

```js
var id = 0;
$('.folder').click(function() {
 if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {      
  alert('already opened');
  return false;
 }
  
 if ($(this).attr('data-id') == id) {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).children('.folder__description').show();
  alert('Opening folder....');
  id = 0;    
  return false;
 }
  
 $('.folder').removeClass('active');
 $('.folder').children('.folder__description').hide(); 
  
 $(this).attr('data-id', Math.random());
 id = $(this).attr('data-id');
 
 setTimeout(function(){
    $('div[data-id="'+ id + '"]').removeClass('active');
      id = 0;
    }, 400);

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #F2F3F5;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;  
}
.folder {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid red;
  margin: 10px
}
.folder:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.folder.active {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.folder__title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.folder__description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="folder">
  <div class="folder__title">New Folder</div>
  <div class="folder__description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="folder">
  <div class="folder__title">New Folder</div>
  <div class="folder__description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Ссылка на [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMejVB)

Возможно я тут не всё учел)) Но, возможно, будет полезно.

Comment: нет поддержки только _On disabled form elements_ все остальное во всех работает

Comment: @Grundy внимательность - не моя лучшая черта :-)

Comment: Бывает :-) по мобильникам, кстати, у них скорее будет использован свое событие типа double tap какого-нибудь

Comment: Вообщем хочу сделать как в файловом менеджере при первом клике на папку в сайдбаре показались свойства из БД а при втором клике она открывалась!

Comment: @John Freeman ну в таком случае из моего кода нужно удалить строку `$(this).children('.folder__description').show();` из того места, где находится сейчас и поставить её сразу после `id = $(this).attr('data-id');` будет так. Хотя скорее вам не только дабл клик надо обрабатывать а еще фокус....... при фокусе - показывать данные, а при даблклике уже что-то делать...тогда тут другая логика будет :-D

Comment: фокус? при даблклике первый клик выделяет и показывает инфу а второй клик открывает

Comment: @JohnFreeman http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXgYaq  ......понимаете штука в чем.... что смысл дабл клика в том, чтоб он срабатывал через заданный интервал времени. а не так, что один раз кликнул, а потом через месяц второй раз кликнул и сработал дабл клик... должен быть задан период времени, между двумя кликами

Comment: ок, а как мне тогда из БД вывести доп. информацию о папке, если у меня их например 20шт. на странице? а folder__description не в диве folder а отдельно в сайдбаре?? спасибо

Comment: @JohnFreeman вот почему нельзя было конкретно сформулировать цели и задачу сразу в вопросе? Очевидный ответ - брать инфу необходимую и выводить в вашем отдельном сайдбаре

Comment: тогда нужно делать блоки folder уникальными например: <div id="folder1" class="folder"> , <div id="folder2" class="folder"> <div id="folder3" class="folder"> и т.д. и уже по id выводить инфо при клике? я что то понять не могу.

Comment: @JohnFreeman Нет. вы когда из БД достаете данные и формируете `html` информацию заносите просто в блок внутри `folder`. Этот блок невидимый. При клике на фолдер эта инфа берется из скрытого элемента кликнутого фолдера и передается в статус бар. При клике на другую папку или при двойном клике статус бар очищается, а папка открывается.. всё.... посмотрите. я переделал первый пример который чисто на `jquery`... если надо - потом переделаю самописный код под аналогичное требование

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  спасибо, я теперь не могу понять как подставить ссылку в двойной клик, делаю так: `$(document).on('dblclick', '.wellprod', function() {
  $('.wellprod').removeClass('active_c');

  $(this).addClass('active_c');
  location.href = link;
});`  где link это переменная с ссылкой, все ок, но эта ссылка получается одна для всех папок на странице, а мне нужно site.com/view.php?id={ID} или если это не категория то site.com/edit.php?id={ID} где {ID} - это уникальный идентификатор из БД

Comment: @JohnFreeman ну так и подставляйте идентификатор из базы. кто мешает? вы же когда в цикле проходитесь формируя `html` можете же нарисовать ссылки динамически - `site.com/view.php?id=<?php echo $dataFromDataBase['data_id']; ?>`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто в цикле при выборке из БД еще прописать: `<? $var = "http://site.com/view.php?id=$folder_id"; ?>
<script>
var link = "<? echo $var ?>";
</script>`  так?

Comment: @JohnFreeman Вы же сказали с ссылкой всё ок......ох...... в цикле у каждого фолдера добавляете атрибут, дата линк.. типа `<div class="folder" data-link="http://site.com/view.php?id=<?php echo $folder_id; ?>">` ....а в функции двойного клика берете значение этого атрибута и подставляете в свой `location.href` ..... типа такого `location.href = $(this).attr('data-link');` всё

Answer (score 1):

1. Создай события клика для двух классов class1 и class2
2. Присвой всем div class1
3. В событиях для class1 добавь код, который меняет элементу аттрибут class с class1 на class2

Comment: Вообщем хочу сделать как в файловом менеджере при первом клике на папку в сайдбаре показались свойства из БД а при втором клике она открывалась!

Comment: Ну ок, в обработчике клика для первого класса выполняешь код для смены класса и отображения дополнительной инфы, а в обработчика для второго класса открываешь свою папку, я так и написал